# Aggregate repository/service pattern

Tags: c#, aggregate, repository-pattern

I have the following for an example that I am wondering when to split this out into other repositories. I have a list of products that have categories, product lines and product types. You can add, delete and edit all of them, but is this service doing too much?:

```
public interface IProductService : IServiceBase
{
    void DeleteProductCategory(int productCategoryId);
    IEnumerable<ProductCategory> GetAllProductCategories();
    IEnumerable<ProductCategory> GetDisplayedProductCategories();
    ProductCategory GetProductCategory(int productCategoryId);
    ProductCategory SaveProductCategory(ProductCategory productCategory);

    void DeleteProductLine(int productLineId);
    IEnumerable<ProductLine> GetAllProductLines();
    IEnumerable<ProductLine> GetDisplayedProductLines();
    ProductLine GetProductLine(int productLineId);
    ProductLine SaveProductLine(ProductLine productLine);

    void DeleteProductType(int productTypeId);
    IEnumerable<ProductType> GetAllProductTypes();
    IEnumerable<ProductType> GetDisplayedProductTypes();
    ProductType GetProductType(int productTypeId);
    ProductType SaveProductType(ProductType productType);

    IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByCategory(int productCategoryId);
    IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByLine(int productLineId);
    IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByType(int productTypeId);
}
```

I am using the repository pattern, so now I have to inject all the repositories for this as well:

```
public ProductService(
        IRepository<Product> productRepo,
        IRepository<ProductCategory> productCategoryRepo,
        IRepository<ProductLine> productLineRepo,
        IRepository<ProductType> productTypeRepo,
        IValidationService validationService,
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork
        )
        : base(validationService, unitOfWork)
    {
        Enforce.ArgumentNotNull(productRepo, "productRepo");
        Enforce.ArgumentNotNull(productCategoryRepo, "productCategoryRepo");
        Enforce.ArgumentNotNull(productLineRepo, "productLineRepo");
        Enforce.ArgumentNotNull(productTypeRepo, "productTypeRepo");

        this.productRepo = productRepo;
        this.productCategoryRepo = productCategoryRepo;
        this.productLineRepo = productLineRepo;
        this.productTypeRepo = productTypeRepo;
    }
```

Seems to me this is a lot of dependencies. When/how should I split them out?

Comment: this could use a real answer, i've been annoyed by this as well

Answer (score 0):

Personally i have desire to create some basic generic service class and then inherit a few services from it.
Something like this

```
public abstract class GeneralService<T>
{
    private IRepository<T> _repository;
    public GeneralService(IRepository<T> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public abstract void Delete(int Id);
    public abstract IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    public abstract IEnumerable<T> GetDisplayed();
    public abstract T Get(int Id);
    public abstract T Save(T t);

    public abstract IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(int Id);
}

public interface IRepository<T>
{
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class ProductService : GeneralService<Product>
{
    ...
}

public class ProductLineService:GeneralService<ProductLine>
{
    ...
}
```